# vb.net listen for parent form event on each child form

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to implement a function on my parent form, that when the event fires, I want to perform actions on all of the child forms that are open. Because any given child form may or may not be open at a given time, I can't handle it directly from the event on the parent form: i.e., cant do the following as Child1 may not be initiated at the time:

```
--Parent Form--
Public Sub ParentEvent()
    DoParentAction()
    DoChild1Action()
    DoChild2Action()
End Sub
```

Is there a way on each child page to listen for ParentEvent() to be fired? essentially, what I want to do is handle the ParentEvent() being fired, on the child page the same as if a button was clicked on the child page, something like this:

```
--Child1--
Public Sub ChildEvent() Handles ParentForm.DoParentAction()
    DoChild1Action()
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this an MDI application?  If so, just loop through the MDIChildren collection to call the procedure.

Comment: Looping through the child forms seems like a good plan, if there not mdi you could have them (children) register themselves with the parent when they loadl

Comment: Why do you want that? If you explain your need, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @LarsTech - I wouldn't go discouraging the OP from following an architecture which is easier to maintain. An event makes much more sense then calling each child form from the parent.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I'm not necessarily discouraging the use of events, but from the simple description of the problem, I don't think events would be the best fit here.  Looping through the forms of a Type or Interface and then calling a method on that object would be simpler than adding events everywhere.  Matter of opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy to do, you just have to step around VB's `WithEvents` and `Handles` syntax to get at it.

```
Public Class ParentForm
    Event OnDoSomething()

    Private Sub DoSomething()
         RaiseEvent OnDoSomething()
    End Sub
End Class
```

and then

```
Public Class ChildForm
   Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        AddHandler ParentForm.OnDoSomething, AddressOf DoSomething
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoSomething()
        ' do something
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChildForm_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) _
                Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        RemoveHandler ParentForm.OnDoSomething, AddressOf DoSomething
    End Sub
End Class
```

It's important to always make sure the event handler is removed before disposing the child form (else you end up with a memory leak).

The above assumes you are using the VB default instance of `ParentForm` - if you're not, obviously you have to reference things accordingly.  A better approach might be to make the parent an argument in the constructor like:

```
 Public Sub New(ByVal parent as ParentForm)
    InitializeComponent()
    AddHandler parent.OnDoSomething, AddressOf DoSomething
 End Sub
```

also, of course, modifying the `RemoveHandler` section as well (you'd need to keep a reference to the parent).  Another option is to hook/unhook in the `ParentChanged` event if this is an MDI application.

The only other caveat is that you can't create any of the child forms in the constructor of the parent form since you end up with self-reference during construction.

Answer (score 5):

Sure.

Add a public event to the parent form:

```
Public Event EventFired(ByVal timestamp As DateTime)
```

In each child form, add a handler:

```
Public Sub ParentEventFired(ByVal timestamp As DateTime)
    Label1.Text = "Child 1: Parent Event Fired (" & timestamp.ToLongTimeString() & ")"
End Sub
```

When you create the child form, add a handler:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim l_child1 = New ChildForm1()
    AddHandler Me.EventFired, AddressOf l_child1.ParentEventFired
    l_child1.Show(Me)
End Sub
```

You can use this approach whether you are using an MDI or simply free-floating windows.

[image: Screenshot]

## FULL CODE

### ParentForm Designer

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class ParentForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.Button3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(166, 23)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Button1.Text = "Open Child 1"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Button2
        '
        Me.Button2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 41)
        Me.Button2.Name = "Button2"
        Me.Button2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(166, 23)
        Me.Button2.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Button2.Text = "Open Child 2"
        Me.Button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Button3
        '
        Me.Button3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 231)
        Me.Button3.Name = "Button3"
        Me.Button3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(166, 23)
        Me.Button3.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Button3.Text = "Fire Event"
        Me.Button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'ParentForm
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(292, 266)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button3)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button2)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.Name = "ParentForm"
        Me.Text = "ParentForm"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents Button2 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Friend WithEvents Button3 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
End Class
```

### ParentForm Code Behind

```
Public Class ParentForm

    Public Event EventFired(ByVal timestamp As DateTime)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim l_child1 = New ChildForm1()
        AddHandler Me.EventFired, AddressOf l_child1.ParentEventFired
        l_child1.Show(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim l_child2 = New ChildForm2()
        AddHandler Me.EventFired, AddressOf l_child2.ParentEventFired
        l_child2.Show(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        RaiseEvent EventFired(DateTime.Now)
    End Sub

End Class
```

### ChildForm1 Designer

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class ChildForm1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 9)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Label1.Text = "Label1"
        '
        'ChildForm1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(292, 266)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.Name = "ChildForm1"
        Me.Text = "ChildForm1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
End Class
```

### ChildForm1 Code Behind

```
Public Class ChildForm1

    Public Sub ParentEventFired(ByVal timestamp As DateTime)
        Label1.Text = "Child 1: Parent Event Fired (" & timestamp.ToLongTimeString() & ")"
    End Sub

End Class
```

### ChildForm2 Designer

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class ChildForm2
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 9)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 1
        Me.Label1.Text = "Label1"
        '
        'ChildForm2
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(292, 266)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.Name = "ChildForm2"
        Me.Text = "ChildForm2"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As System.Windows.Forms.Label
End Class
```

### ChildForm2 Code Behind

```
Public Class ChildForm2

    Public Sub ParentEventFired(ByVal timestamp As DateTime)
        Label1.Text = "Child 2: Parent Event Fired (" & timestamp.ToLongTimeString() & ")"
    End Sub

End Class
```